# XML change value from parent to child

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML:

```
<destinos>
 <destino>
   <location>Spain</location>
     <programas>
       <item></item>
       <item></item>
     </programas>
 </destino>
 <destino>
   <location>France</location>
     <programas>
       <item></item>
       <item></item>
     </programas>
 </destino>
</destinos>
```

I need to include or copy the value of "Location" within each "item" and I am not able to do so.

```
<destinos>
 <destino>
   <location>Spain</location>
     <programas>
       <item>
        <location>Spain</location>
       </item>
       <item>
        <location>Spain</location>
       </item>
     </programas>
 </destino>
 <destino>
   <location>France</location>
     <programas>
       <item>
        <location>France</location>
       </item>
       <item>
        <location>France</location>
       </item>
     </programas>
 </destino>
</destinos>
```

I have no knowledge of PHP and I have been reading but I can't find the solution.

If someone could help me and explain I would be very grateful.

My code:

```
$url = file_get_contents("archive.xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($url); 

$changes = $xml->xpath("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'item')]");

foreach ($changes as $change) 
    $change[0] = $xml->destinos->destino->location;

header('Content-Type: application/xml');

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use [xpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) with [addChild](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) with with the value of the location:

```
$url = file_get_contents("archive.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);
$changes = $xml->xpath("/destinos/destino");

foreach ($changes as $change) {
    $text = (string)$change->location;
    foreach ($change->xpath("programas/item") as $i) {
        $i->addChild("location", $text);
    }
}
header('Content-Type: application/xml');

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output

```
<destinos>
    <destino>
        <location>Spain</location>
        <programas>
            <item><location>Spain</location></item>
            <item><location>Spain</location></item>
        </programas>
    </destino>
    <destino>
        <location>France</location>
        <programas>
            <item><location>France</location></item>
            <item><location>France</location></item>
        </programas>
    </destino>
</destinos>
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/NSgmr)

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleXML, you can just use object notation to access the various elements of the document, this stops the need for XPath and can also make the code more readable...

```
$url = file_get_contents("archive.xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);

foreach ($xml->destino as $destino) {
    // Process each item
    foreach ( $destino->programas->item as $item )  {
        // Set the location from the destino location value
        $item->location = (string)$destino->location;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/xml');

echo $xml->asXML();
```

One thing to note is that when using SimpleXML, the root node (`<destinos>` in this case) is the `$xml` object.  This is why `$xml->destino` is accessing the `<destino>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

With DOM you can append clones of the location nodes to the respective item elements.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate the location child of the destino elements
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//destino/location') as $location) {
    // iterate the item nodes inside the same parent node 
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('parent::*/programas/item', $location) as $item) {
        // append a copy of the location to the item
        $item->appendChild($location->cloneNode(TRUE));
    }

}

echo $document->saveXML();
```